# adding log messages to openssl source code, but not printed out

Tags: openssl

I run into issues loading certificate on openssl 1.1.1d version, while the cert is readable from openssl 1.0.2r. The error message is as follows:

```
bash-4.4$ /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl x509 -inform pem -in aa.txt -noout -text
Here is the entrance of OPENSSL 
unable to load certificate
140245985331008:error:0D0E20DD:asn1 encoding routines:c2i_ibuf:illegal padding:crypto/asn1/a_int.c:187:
140245985331008:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:627:Field=serialNumber, Type=X509_CINF
140245985331008:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:627:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
140245985331008:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:crypto/pem/pem_oth.c:33:
```

I added log message to the start of the c2i_ibuf function(a_int.c:187), build and install openssl, but the log message did not show up. Here is what I added. Same issue on the message added at pem_oth.c.  While the message added at the start of x509_main as below shows up.  Can any one help on this?
By the way, the openssl issue I run into is the same as [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4320), I used the certificate in the link (can be found [here](https://crt.sh/?id=1914312)). Thanks.

```
static size_t c2i_ibuf(unsigned char *b, int *pneg, const unsigned char *p, size_t plen)
{
    //the following are not printed. 
    printf("at c2i_ibuf\n");
    printf(p);
    printf("\nafter print p\n");
    printf("Serial number is %s\n", p);

    int neg, pad;
    /* Zero content length is illegal */
    if (plen == 0) {
        ASN1err(ASN1_F_C2I_IBUF, ASN1_R_ILLEGAL_ZERO_CONTENT);
        return 0;
    }
....
}

void *PEM_ASN1_read_bio(d2i_of_void *d2i, const char *name, BIO *bp, void **x,
                        pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)
{
    const unsigned char *p = NULL;
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    long len;
    char *ret = NULL;
    **//Not printed** 
    printf("start of PEM_ASN1_read_bio");
    ........
}
   int x509_main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
    **//this line is printed**  
    printf("Here is the entrance of OPENSSL \n");
    ASN1_INTEGER *sno = NULL;
    ASN1_OBJECT *objtmp = NULL;
   ....
  }
```

Comment: To be clear, as explained in the link you gave, that cert is illegal and 1.1.1 is right to reject it and 1.0.2 was wrong to accept it. (_And_ it expired 13 years ago, or would have if it were legal.) When you built your custom OpenSSL is it linked static or dynamic, and if dynamic are the libraries specified by rpath or similar (depending on your OS, which you didn't identify), and if not how did you configure the dynamic linker on your system (ditto)? Note: these issues are not specific to OpenSSL but common to almost all libraries used in C.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for the input. Somehow we run into a certificate have the same error message as in the link when consumed by openssl. The certificate is generated by strongswan, I wanted to triage/debug how is the serial number got processed by openssl. I was just using the default ./config command. did not specify the rpath. Let me try that. If you have steps to build openssl with changes, can you point me? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger? That's been the preferred way to look at code, at least if compiled like C, since roughly the Richard Nixon presidency. But if you want changes (or just debugging symbols), the default config in 1.1.0 up is dynamic linking, so you must cause your `openssl` excecutable to dyn-link your `libssl` and `libcrypto` instead of the system ones. One way is a linker option with `rpath` canonical but it may be different depending on your system; the other way is to configure the dynamic linker at runtime, also system-dependent. ...

Comment: ... The other approach is to config with `no-shared` which gives you all the code in a single, huge executable. This is usually bad for production uses, but fine for a debugging case like yours.